Show that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq b)$ tends to zero as $n\to \infty$ for $X_n\sim B(n,p)$
I found this question in "Probability Essentials" of Jacod and Protter, exercise 5.13:

For $X_n\sim B(n,p)$ with fixed $p$ show, that for any fixed $b>0$ it holds that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq b)$ tends to $0$ for $n\to \infty$.

Based on the previous content of the book (which includes only basic definitions on random variables and probability spaces) I would have expected to be able to either use the Markov inequality (which doesn't really seem applicable in this case) or to simply calculate starting from
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq b)=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor b \rfloor} \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} 
\end{equation}
I would have only considered the $\binom{n}{i}$ and $(1-p)^{n}$ part since $(\frac{p}{1-p})^{i}$ can be bounded by taking $i=0$ or $i=b$.
Now my question would be to you how I can show that $(1-p)^{n}$ converges stronger to $0$ than the sum of $\binom{n}{i}$ tends to infinity. Since it doesn't seem like a nice approach to me I would also be very open to input of how I can arrive at the result in another way.
Thanks a lot!

The sum of the combinations is a polynomial of degree $b.$

So with this, as I already started, I would end up with the $(\frac{p}{1-p})^i$ part being bounded, $(1-p)^n$ going to zero, as $(1-p)<1$. Then would it be possible to show something like $xn^b+yn^{b-1}+zn^{b-2}\dots$ goes to infinity slower than $(1-p)^n$?

Any polynomial divided by an exponential with base greater than 1 (you really mean that the reciprocal $1/(1-p)^n$ goes to infinity, because we want the original thing tending to zero) converges to zero. One way of showing this would be to use l'Hôpital's rule $b$ times.

Let $b,p>0$. There is a constant $C>0$, such that
$$\max_{i\in[0,b]\cap\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i < C$$
Then, for any $n>b$ and $i\in[0,b]\cap\mathbb{N}$, you find
$$\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}\le C\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}(1-p)^n\le Cn^i(1-p)^n$$
Since $0<(1-p)<1$, there exists $\delta>0$ with $\delta =-\log(1-p)$, such that
$$n^i(1-p)^n=e^{i\log(n)-n\delta}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\left(i\frac{\log(n)}{n}-\delta\right)}\longrightarrow 0$$
for $n\longrightarrow \infty$, since $$\frac{\log(n)}{n}\longrightarrow 0$$
for $n\longrightarrow \infty$ by L'Hôpital's rule. This yields
$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}P(X_n\le b)=0$$

For independent and identically distributed $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n\sim\operatorname{Ber}(p)$, you can rewrite $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$. Using the central limit theorem, you find
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_n\le b)
&=P(\frac{X_n-E[X_n]}{\sqrt{Var[X_n]}}\le\frac{b-E[X_n]}{\sqrt{Var[X_n]}})\\
&=P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\le \frac{b-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}})\approx\Phi(\frac{b-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}})
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
Since $\frac{b-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\longrightarrow-\infty$ for $n\longrightarrow\infty$, you find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n\le b)=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\Phi(x)=0$$
More detailed:
Since $\frac{b-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\longrightarrow-\infty$ for $n\longrightarrow\infty$, you find for any $\varepsilon>0$ a large $K>0$ and a natural number $N$, such that for any $n\ge N$, it holds
$$\Phi(-K)<\varepsilon$$
as well as
$$\frac{b-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}<-K$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_n\le b)
&=P(\frac{X_n-E[X_n]}{\sqrt{Var[X_n]}}\le\frac{b-E[X_n]}{\sqrt{Var[X_n]}})\\
&=P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\le \frac{b-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}})\\
&\le P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\le -K)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the central limit theorem, you find
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n\le b)\le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\le -K)=\Phi(-K)<\varepsilon$$
Since the choice of $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it necessarily holds
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n\le b)=0$$

Thanks a lot, your proof is very nice and I appreciate the effort! However, the solution would have to be done without using the central limit theorem. I do see that my question has not specified the restricted amount of definitions and theorems that are available for the proof, so I edited it.

Here's an alternative coupling argument.
Let $(Y_{k})_{k\geq 1}$ be a collection of iid $Bern(p)$ variates.
Now,  let $A_{k}$ be the event $\{Y_{k}=1\}$. Then $A_{k}$ are independent events with $P(A_{k})=p>0$
Thus $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_{k})=\infty$ . Thus the Borel-Cantelli Lemma tells you that with probability $P\bigg\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for infinitely many k}\bigg\}=1$ and hence $P\bigg\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost finitely many indices}\bigg\}=0$
Now, $X_{n}$ has the same distribution as $\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}$.
Now fix an integer $b>0$ and let $n>b$.
Thus $P(X_{n}\leq b)=P(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\leq b)=P(\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost b many indices for }\,k\leq n \})$
Now notice that the events $B_{n}:=\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost b many indices for}\, k\leq n\}$ are decreasing, i.e. $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_{n}$ and $B_{n}\downarrow\bigg\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost b many indices}\bigg\}\subseteq \bigg\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost finitely many indices}\bigg\} $ which has $0$ probability as we have shown above.
Now by continuity of Probability Measure,
\begin{align}P(X_{n}\leq b)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} &\, P\bigg\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost b many indices}\bigg\}\\\\&\leq P\bigg\{Y_{k}=1\,\text{for atmost finitely many indices}\bigg\}=0\end{align}
which shows that $P(X_{n}\leq b)\to 0$
This argument also tells you that for any postiive real $a$, you have that $P(X_{n+1}> a)\geq P(X_{n}> a)$ (or one can also write it as $P(X_{n}\leq a)\geq P(X_{n+1}\leq a)$) which is called "Stochastic Dominance". Note that if you were asked to show it by explicitly proving inequalities with the CDF or pmf, then it would become difficult. But, since this is a statement about distributions, one can just write it in terms of the events for $Y_{k}$'s which are much easier to handle.

This is much simpler than what the other answers suggest, since $b$ is fixed. Take $n$ so large that $n/2 \ge b$ and $n \ge b+1$. Then for $i \le b, \binom{n}{i} \le \binom{n}{b}$ (why?). So, we can bound $$ P(X_n \le b) = \sum_{i \le b} \binom{n}{b} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \le (b+1)\binom{n}{b} (1-p)^{n-b}\\ \le n^{b+1} e^{-(n-b)p} = \exp( (b+1) \log n + bp - np).$$ But as $n \to \infty, \frac{(b+1) \log n + bp}{np} \to 0$ (i.e., $\log n$ grows much more slowly than $n$). So for large enough $n$, $(b+1) \log n + bp < np/2,$ giving us that for large $n$, $P(X_n \le b) \le \exp(-np/2),$ and now the limit is trivial.

Indeed, since $X_n$ is distributed as the sum of $n$ i.i.d $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ random variables, by the central limit theorem,
$$\sqrt n\left(\frac{X_n}{n}-p\right)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N\left(0,p(1-p)\right).$$
Let $F_n$ and $F$ be the distribution functions of $\sqrt n\left(\frac{X_n}{n}-p\right)$ and $N(0,p(1-p))$ respectively.
It is important to note that the limiting distribution $F$ is continuous, so that the convergence of $F_n$ to $F$ is uniform (Polya's theorem):
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}|F_n(x)-F(x)|\longrightarrow 0.$$
This implies that, for any real sequence $\{x_n\}$,
$$F_n(x_n) -F(x_n) \longrightarrow 0 .$$
Now,
$$P(X_n\le b )=P\left(\sqrt n\left(\frac{X_n}{n}-p\right)\le \sqrt n\left(\frac{b}{n}-p\right)\right).$$
Take $x_n=\sqrt n\left(\frac{b}{n}-p\right)$, so that
$$F_n(x_n)-F(x_n)=P(X_n\le b)-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt n(\frac{b}{n}-p)}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right) \longrightarrow 0. \tag{1}$$
But
$$\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt n(\frac{b}{n}-p)}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right)\longrightarrow \Phi(-\infty)=0. \tag{2}$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ together imply $$P(X_n\le b) \longrightarrow 0.$$
